# Group by X or Y?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, group-concat

I'm trying to figure out how to `GROUP BY` on multiple columns. I want to group items when the SSN *or* the address matches. For example, here are three records:

```
account_number | name         | ssn         | address
---------------+--------------+-------------+----------------------
23952352340    | SMITH INC    | 123-45-6789 | P.O. BOX 123
3459450340     | JOHN SMITH   | 123-45-6789 | 123 EVERGREEN TERRACE
45949459494    | JANE SMITH   | 395-23-1924 | 123 EVERGREEN TERRACE
```

And here's what I'd like to end up with:

```
names
----------------------
SMITH INC, JOHN SMITH, JANE SMITH
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you are grouping by Name. Can you give a better example?

Comment: Sure. I edited to include three distinct names.

Comment: If you removed `3459450340` from the table, that would leave you with two groups instead of one, right?

Comment: Yes. Jane's only relationship to SMITH INC is the fact that she shares an address with its owner. If that relationship goes away, the two customers belong in two separate groups.

Comment: Also, if Quassnoi can't figure it out, I don't think anybody can, based on what I've seen in the past. :)

Comment: What would happen if you added another row `9999999999    | JOE BLOGGS    | 9876-54-321 | P.O. BOX 123` would that go into the same bucket? At the moment all of the ones in the group at least have a common relationship with `3459450340`

Comment: @Martin: it would go into its own bucket since it's reachable by no records from the first bucket.

Comment: @Quassnoi - It has the same address as `SMITH INC`.

Comment: @Martin: Interesting question. The goal here is to determine which accounts/customers belong in the same household so we aren't sending two pieces of the same mail to the same person. It would be quite odd for Joe Bloggs to share a PO box with Smith, Inc., but I suppose if that were to happen, we would just include Joe Bloggs in that same household. It's pretty safe to say we never encounter that case in practice, but I think the rule to follow is to follow the chain of linking as far as it goes, and put all those people in one group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this easily in `MySQL`.

The problem is that the relation "is similar to" as you define it is not transitive. In your example, `Smith Inc` is similar to `John Smith` (per `SSN`) and `John Smith` is similar to `Jane Smith` (per name), but `Smith Inc` is not similar to `Jane Smith`. So there is no single value that all records could be compared with and `GROUP BY` won't help here.

In other systems which support recursion you could build a transitive closure of this relation which would allow grouping, but this is not an easy task in `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT
    name,
    ssn,
    COUNT(*)
FROM TheTable
GROUP BY
    name,
    ssn
```

Comment: I'm not trying to group by name, THEN SSN. I'm trying to group by name OR SSN.